# Memory management and performSelectorInBackground:

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Which is right? This:

```
NSArray* foo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil];
[bar performSelectorInBackground:@selector(baz:) withObject:foo];

- (void)baz:(NSArray*)foo {
    ...
    [foo release];
}
```

Or:

```
NSArray* foo = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil] autorelease];
[bar performSelectorInBackground:@selector(baz:) withObject:foo];

- (void)baz:(NSArray*)foo {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ...
    [pool release];
}
```

I know the first one works, but Clang complains about it, so I wonder if there's a better pattern to use.

I would "just try out" the 2nd one, but with autoreleasing, who knows whether the absence of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means that you're doing it right or that you just got lucky...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First is wrong.

performSelectorInBackground:withObject: retains both bar and foo until task is performed. Thus, you should autorelease foo when you create it and let performSelectorInBackground:withObject take care of the rest. See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:)

Latter is correct because you autorelease foo when you create it. Autorelease pool that you create inside baz has nothing do with correctness of foo's memory management. That autorelease pool is needed for autoreleased objects **inside** pool allocation and release in baz, it doesn't touch foo's retain count at all.

Comment: I should clarify: you MUST create and drain an autorelease pool inside -baz:, unless you KNOW that nothing will be sent an -autorelease method inside there. The best rule of thumb is to assume that will happen and create/drain an autorelease pool, as in example 2. But use [pool drain], not [pool release].

Comment: Exactly as Jim Dovey said: you usually need to create autorelease pool just like you do for main function (see Thread Programming Guide). It's just important to understand that this pool has nothing to do with autorelease of foo.

Comment: @Jim, the docs stress that if you are in a memory-managed environment (which I believe we are, iPhone OS), calling `drain` is equivalent to calling `release`.

Comment: True— but -drain will also do the appropriate thing for any environment, so use it, in case your code ever moves to the desktop or collected memory arrives on the iPhone.

Comment: @TeemuKurppa Сould you please quote Apple docs where it states that `performSelectorInBackground` retains `self` and its `withObject` argument? Downvoted for now.

Comment: @Aliaksei, Apple has quite likely edited their documentation since this answer was written (2009). They don't mention it anymore, presumably because iOS now has automatic reference counting.

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach now would in fact be to do:

```
NSArray* foo = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", nil] autorelease];
[bar performSelectorInBackground:@selector(baz:) withObject:foo];

- (void)baz:(NSArray*)foo {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ...
    }
}
```