# Abort NSXML download halfway through to avoid crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsxmlparser

In my iPhone app, how do i go about aborting the download of an XML file halfway through downloading it, ie. like in the viewDidUnload method? What exactly do i need to set to nil or is that not what i do?

Comment: You need to provide some more implementation details. How exactly are you downloading the file? Did you simply plug in the URL into the NSXMLParser's `initWithContentsOfURL:` method, or are you downloading the file separately, for example using NSURLConnection? And to be clear, you are referring specifically to stopping the download of the file, not the parsing, correct?

Comment: Correct. If the user clicks the back button on the nav bar while its downloading then it crashes. If you see mu question here, all is explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370031/iphone-app-crashes-if-view-is-swapped-during-data-download any help, greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a crashing problem. Make sure that You set all your downloading DELEGATES to nil when stopping the downloading.